Customizing Angular Material MatChip
I'm trying to customize a MatChip and cannot get it to appear as desired.
The out of the box MatChip has 3 behaviours I am trying to customize plus add a fourth of my own

The default color
The hover color change
The onClick color change
Addition of a label below the chip which must appear/behave exactly like the chip it is attached to

What I have tried
I have managed to change the default color (item 1) using [style.background-color] ... no success with [class.my-class] as class was applied but the value superceded somewhere else in the style cascade.
I have the label in place (item 4) but it is not behaving like the chip it is attached to because I can't figure out how to make the label behave like the main chip for the color changes associated with hover and onClick. When you hover or click the chip, the distinct color separation between the label and the chip is visible because the chip is changing color but the label is not. How do I make the label and chip appear/behave the same so it just appears and behaves like a single customized chip.
Stackblitz Demo A list of employees, each represented as a chip, the manager will be marked with a special label
Default state (no line visible between chip and label)

Hover state (ie hover over the chip, not the label ... feint line visible between chip and label)

OnClick state (ie click and hold, clear line visible between chip and label)


You can only achieve CSS colors of different states, but you can not achieve ripple effect happening on click of chip, because chip a complex DOM structure to handle ripple effect.

You can use a combination of overriding the default CSS variables and custom classes to achieve the desired effect.
We use .custom-chip-color * selector to configure the new CSS variables you want to use for the chip colors.
We will configure this color for manager section, using CSS class .custom-chip-color .mat-mdc-standard-chip:not(.mdc-evolution-chip--disabled):hover .manager-tab.
.custom-chip-color * {
  --mdc-chip-elevated-container-color: lightgreen;
  --mdc-chip-hover-state-layer-color: green;
}

.custom-chip-color .mat-mdc-chip:hover .mat-mdc-chip-focus-overlay {
  background-color: var(--mdc-chip-hover-state-layer-color) !important;
}


.custom-chip-color .mat-mdc-standard-chip:not(.mdc-evolution-chip--disabled):hover {
  background-color: var(--mdc-chip-hover-state-layer-color) !important;
}
.custom-chip-color .mat-mdc-standard-chip:not(.mdc-evolution-chip--disabled):hover .manager-tab {
  background-color: var(--mdc-chip-hover-state-layer-color) !important;
}

Stackblitz Demo

I'm not sure I entirely follow the solution. I may not have explained the problem well enough. I have updated the original post to add some images to show the initial state of the issue. I still see these issues in the Stackblitz Demo link provided above unless I have misunderstood something

@Fred2020 How about this? stackblitz

The onHover issue has been resolved for the Manager chip but it's also being applied to the onHover of an Employee chip also. Only the Manager chip would have this red color applied. The onClick issue still remains. With the onClick, it's good that the color of the chip changes to a different shade of red but I'd like the label to change also to this different shade.
